# vba prevent the user from updating a table powered by power query (without breaking the link)

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

sorry, for the translation error :-( on my previous question, I will rephrase it, replacing be able with not be able.

I created an EXCEL VBA application, which imports files into a table using a PowerQuery query. Once the table is updated by the query that I run in VBA, I would like the user not to be able to update the table (right click to refresh), or via the Powerquery query panel. So far all my research has not been successful, and I am open to all ideas. THANK YOU

Comment: Same question like yesterday?

Comment: Copy that table in vba and paste as values

Comment: Reposting the same question doesn't help us understand it.  As @horseyride commented - it can be done with VBA copying and pasting the values to a new workbook. [EXCEL VBA POWERQUERY prohibit the updating of a table powered by a power query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77463546/excel-vba-powerquery-prohibit-the-updating-of-a-table-powered-by-a-power-query)

Comment: Write the power query in VBA (and delete once run) - stops the refresh. Protect sheet with password to stop the data being updated

Comment: So you got an answer? Does that solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in customizing the banner which makes certain basic Excel functions inoperable.

Inserting the following line into the beginning of the xml code of a custom ribbon tab will make the table refresh function inoperable.

```
<command idMso="WorkbookRefreshAll" enabled="false"/>
```

on the other hand, updating will always be possible using VBA.

This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You could also right-click the table and select Refresh.

Answer (score 1):

This would stop the user from having access to the query by copying the table to a new workbook.  They can still manually update the table, so will need to lock the sheet.

```
Public Sub Test_Export()

    'Create a workbook containing a single sheet.
    Dim wrkbk As Workbook
    Set wrkbk = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    'Set reference to sheet containing your PowerQuery table.
    'ThisWorkbook is the file containing this code - assumes you add this code
    'to the workbook containing the PowerQuery.
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Set reference to PowerQuery table on your sheet.
    'You'll need to update "Table1" to the name of your table.
    Dim MyQueryTable As ListObject
    Set MyQueryTable = srcSht.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    'Copy the table.
    MyQueryTable.Range.Copy
    
    'Paste the values and formats to the new workbook.
    With wrkbk.Worksheets(1)
        .Name = srcSht.Name
        With .Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```